How to Create a 3D Texture with Depth from Slices for KTX2 in Three.js?
I’m trying to create a 3D texture with depth using KTX2 files for volume rendering in Three.js. I have a KTX2 file that, when extracted using,produces 64 slices named output_depth*.png, each of size 64x64.
output_depth2.png
ouput_depth22.png
ouput_depth39.png
output_depth59.png
The slices appear to represent some baked model or pattern, and the texture has depth when used as a 3D texture. However, I can’t figure out how to generate similar slices from my own model or texture.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Converted my slices into a KTX2 file using available tools, but the results don’t match the depth or structure of the original KTX2.
Explored various methods to bake my model or texture to generate similar slices, but without success.

I’ve attached the KTX2 file and extracted slices for reference. Can anyone guide me on:

How these slices might have been created?
The exact process or tools I can use to generate slices like this
from my model or texture?
Best practices for creating a KTX2 file suitable for 3D textures with
depth in Three.js?

I’d greatly appreciate any advice, examples, or resources that could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!
Original ktx2 file : x_64.ktx2
